# Add event listener to Flex components inside a repeater

Tags: apache-flex, repeater, event-listener

I want to add an event listener to each component inside a repeater, but don't know how. Here's some code I have tried:

```
<mx:Repeater id="rp" dataProvider="{dataProvider}" width="100%">
   <mx:Button id="attach" creationComplete="addListeners(attach[rp.currentIndex])"/>
</mx:Repeater>
```

This doesn't work.  creationComplete is not called until the repeater has finished instead of (as I expected) when the creation of the button is complete.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

BTW - I also tried placing the creationComplete on the parent component to the repeater, but it would only be called the first time the component was rendered (the data inside the repeater sometimes changes) so that didn't work.

Comment: Do - not - use - Repeater! Use a List instead. Or in this specific case probably a ButtonBar.

Comment: @RIAStar isn't that for something similar to an HTML select box?  this isn't what I need.  I dumbed down the example a little, but inside the repeater I need a button, a checkbox and a label

Comment: Then use a List and put all that stuff in a custom ItemRenderer. If you use Repeater you're in a world of pain - as you probably already know.

Comment: @RIAstar  Thanks for your comments.  Can you please expand upon or refer to some resources where it describes the virtues of using List over Repeater?  At the surface, I'm not seeing the advantages.

Comment: There's no reason not you use Repeaters, and Lists have their own difficulties, especially if you're new to Flex and don't know how to write your own measure override.

Comment: It's just my personal experience that whenever I tried to use Repeater to do anything else than the "instruction manual implementation", I would run into some roadblock pretty soon. I have never had that kind of difficulty with the List approach. I have no resources to back that opinion up though. But the main argument would be that it behaves differently from all other Flex components. Also notice that the Repeater was dropped in the Spark component set.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an Event defined in metadata, it can be as simple as adding click="myClickHandler(event)".  You can also do something like this:

```
<yourNS:YourComponent id="foo>
    <creationComplete>
        <fx:Script>
            (foo[yourRepeater.currentIndex] as EventDispatcher).addEventListener('the event', yourEventHandler);
        </fx:Script>
    </creationComplete>
</yourNS:YourComponent >
```